# Remove Monterey hidden keybindings

Tags: keyboard, finder, mission-control

I recently ran into a problem, I assume because of an update to macOS.

I've always had ctrl 1 bound to switch to a different layout in mission control. Out of nowhere it stopped working after a restart (and I think a small update to Monterey, don't remember which one.)

I figured out that Ctrl 1, 2, 3 etc. are "hidden keybinds" and I can't seem to override Ctrl 1 specifically.

Ctrl 2 and Ctrl 3 are perfectly fine to override, but Ctrl 1 is still bound to set a "finder tag".

I have bound them all through System preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission control -> Switch to desktop 1, 2 & 3 (for Ctrl 1, 2 & 3).

Is there a way to unset this default hidden keybind for Ctrl 1? Or make sure that my custom keybind overrides this one? This seems like an obvious bug in the OS to me but maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: Do you have a short or extended keyboard? On an extended, the 10-key numbers & 'qwerty' numbers are considered distinct [which you cannot tell from the Shortcuts pref pane] Ctrl/num has always been default for Spaces, but the initial default is to 'qwerty' not 10-key. I can confirm default behaviour did not change in Monterey; nor since maybe El Capitan or before. I could suggest checking the Services & App Shortcuts sub categories to see if something has snuck in an override. Also clear & re-add the shortcut in Mission Control.

Comment: These are all set to the 10-key pad, but there is no distinction at all, no hint that they are not the 'qwerty' equivalents. https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3wwH.jpg

Comment: I've tried re-adding them with no luck. And it definitely isn't because of my keyboard. I have my bindings set up almost exactly as the image you provided and everything works except for Ctrl-1. And no overrides in any other place.

Comment: Ctrl-1 is simply bound to add a "tag" to a file or folder. And for some reason this hidden binding takes precedence over any other manual binding I give it.. I am on Monterey 12.5 right now and I suspect I was on 12.2 or 12.3 before updating but I don't remember. All I know is that it worked fine before updating.

Comment: It has to be some 3rd party application or service that's 'stealing' it. There is no Finder command to add a tag, there is only the right click menu followed by a click on the correct colour dot. You couldn't add that as a key command by any regular user method.

Comment: Thats why I said "hidden", I found it out by this video explaining it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=go1AmFkE4Jo&t=60s&ab_channel=macmostvideo

Comment: oooh…kaay… 30 years of Mac & I had no idea that existed:\ So… how is it that a million other people haven't found it by accident then wondered what happened? Ctrl/num has been default for Spaces since it was first introduced. I just tested switching my Spaces keys to the ones above qwerty [I usually use 10-key], which just overrides the labelling behaviour for any numbers I assign to Spaces. So, for instance ctr/1 & ctrl/2 switch Spaces, Ctrl/3 & higher assign a label.

Comment: hm, alright thanks for testing it. I suppose it has to be some kind of 3rd party application then, even though I've tried turning basically everything off with no success

Comment: Yeah, that could have an effect. I don't use separate Spaces so it's not something i can test [& switching it on temporarily makes a helluva mess of my workflow ;)

Comment: Yea makes sense, thanks for taking your time though :) might try to upgrade to Ventura and just hope it resolves the issue..

Answer (score 1):

So after a few days I finally found the solution. For anyone else with this issue these two commands will reset the mission control, which I would assume happens on a restart but apparently not. Anyway, this solved it for me, after excluding any possibility of third party applications being the culprit.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool FALSE

killall Dock
```